# Animating UIView - How to keep track of Position?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-animation

i animate (move) a subclassed UIImageView like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];  
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1];  
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];  
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES]; 
if (position == 0) position = 1;
if (position > 6) position--;    
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(position*120, 0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

then, i want to highlight it by let it pulsate:

```
CAKeyframeAnimation *bounce = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
CATransform3D forward = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.3, 1.3, 1);
CATransform3D back = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.7, 0.7, 1);
CATransform3D forward2 = CATransform3DMakeScale(1.2, 1.2, 1);
CATransform3D back2 = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.9, 0.9, 1);
[bounce setValues:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity],
                   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:forward],
                   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:back],
                   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:forward2],
                   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:back2],
                   [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity],
                   nil]];
[bounce setDuration:0.6];
[[super layer] addAnimation:bounce forKey:@"bounceanimation"];
```

That all works. It's get moved by 120 Pixel but when a call the pulsate code it will pulsate on its original position, not where i've just moved it. why is that and how can i change it?

tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here's your problem:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(position*120, 0);
```

Notice that you are **translating** the view to another spot, but like any transform, the original stats of the object stay the same.

All you have to do is translate that code into a setFrame: method so that it actually moves the image.

Comment: finally got it! thanks! changed that to [self setFrame:CGRectMake(30+position*120, self.frame.origin.y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

Answer (score 0):

Dont worry! just add this

```
   bounce.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
```

It will make you your animation stay at end point.